# Why does external process in ASP.NET application fail?

Tags: asp.net, putty

I have some code that is running in an ASP.NET application that runs a command line process that uses PSCP.EXE (Putty) to copy a file from an external Linux server to the local server.  When I run the ASP.NET application interactively by using the Run command in Visual Studio 2010 it works fine.  However, when I deploy the application to IIS (on the same server!) and try to run it I get an error coming back from the PSCP.EXE command line.  The error is this:

Fatal: Network error: Connection timed out

I did a little research about that PSCP.EXE error and the only thing I found was people suggesting that the port needed to be specified.  But I don't think that would apply to me since it works fine when I run the app through Visual Studio.

Does anyone know why I would get a connection timed out error when running the command from IIS 7 on my box, but when I run it through Visual Studio on the same box it works fine?

Here is my code:

```
string _pscpExePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PSCPExePath"];
string _localOptionsFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalOptionsFileFolder"];
string _remoteOptionsLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RemoteOptionsFileLocation"];

ProcessStartInfo _procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + _pscpExePath + " -pw " + App.ConfigData.ModemAdminPassword + " root@" + App.ConfigData.ModemIPAddress + ":" + _remoteOptionsLocation + " " + _localOptionsFolder);
_procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
_procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
_procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
_procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

using (Process _proc = Process.Start(_procStartInfo))
{
  using (StreamReader _reader = _proc.StandardOutput)
  {
    string _result = _reader.ReadToEnd();
    log.Info("Get Options File Result = " + _result);
  }

  using (StreamReader _error = _proc.StandardError)
  {
    string _result = _error.ReadToEnd();
    log.Info("Get Options File Error = " + _result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was mistaken.  There was a different reason that the IIS site was unable to connect to the linux server.  Everything is working properly now.  This question can be marked as answered and could even be removed as it really wasn't an issue with the code or anything.